# Expectation of $\max(X, 0)$ for scalar normal distributed random variable $X$

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $X$ be a scalar, normal distributed random variable. I want to compute the expectation of $f(x) = \max(X, 0)$. I know that I can compute the expectation by solving the following integral

$$E[\max(0, X)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_0^{\infty}x\cdot\exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})dx$$

Is this approach right and how do I compute this integral? Is there an analytic solution?

I would be happy if someone could help me solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The computation here is similar to the computations for the [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) which doesn't seem to have expressions that don't involve the error function.

Comment: $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_0^{\infty}(x-\mu)\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}\right)\,dx$ can be handled analytically but leaves you to deal with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_0^{\infty}\mu\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}\right) \, dx$ which raises the same difficulty as any definite normal integral.  So there is an answer for the mean of a censored normal distribution if you can use $\Phi(x)$

Comment: @Samuel...and the integrand you showed is wrong. the exponent is $-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$

Comment: @tommik Thank you! I corrected it!